# Can I get SIM card at Pudong International Airport?

Tags: airports, cellphones, internet, shanghai

I want to get a SIM card at arrival at Pudong International Airport, and stay in Shanghai for 14 days.

I'm looking for a SIM card that is either from China Unicom or China Telecom, with 4G/LTE compatible. Data only SIM card is sufficient for me. If possible, I starve for tethering and unlimited data plan.

Is it available at the airport?

Comment: Check out this link. https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g308272-i2804-k5466294-Pre_paid_SIM_Card_at_Pudong_Airport-Shanghai.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried it by myself and found one counter at the baggge claim floor. It is the same counter as the mobile Wi-Fi router rental, and they only sell China Unicom SIM card.

The SIM they provide is a bit expensive, with 4G/LTE, limited data and tethering being available. It expires in 30 days.

The price is the following, though they have other plans as well (e.g. 8GB, 2GB).

- 3GB: 300 RMB
- 4GB: 350 RMB
- 5GB: 400 RMB

Comment: you're likely getting a better deal in any phone store in town, especially if you or someone with you speaks a bit of Chinese or you run into someone with basic knowledge of English. Anycase +1

Comment: @mts Yeah I thought about it while purchasing. But I cannot tolerate getting on a train from the airport without the network, so I purchased it anyway :=)

Answer (score 5):

Last time I was at Pudong Airport, China Unicom had a small stall in the baggage reclaim hall. Otherwise, there is also a China Unicom stall in the arrivals hall (T2).